# Is there a way to pass a command line argument when running a cell in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter

I would like to pass a command line argument while running a cell in a Jupyter Notebook?

Is this functionality supported? If so how can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? What is a _command line argument_ in this context?

Comment: An argument that you would pass after calling the python script from a command window at the time of execution and read with sys.argv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple cases, just as reading in some numbers from the command line, `input` can be used.

In the following example, a list of lists for user inputs is generated:

```
testcases = int(input().strip())
stuff = [[int(x) for x in input().strip().split()] for case in range(testcases)]
```